# Group Ring/Algebra and Functions of Positive Type

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, terminology, group-rings

Given a group $G$, we can form its complex group ring/algebra $\Bbb{C}[G]$, which either be described as the set of all finite formal sums of group elements with complex coefficients or as all the functions $G \to \Bbb{C}$ with finite support. Question:

> Given a function $f : G \to \Bbb{C}$ of finite support, what does it mean to say that $f$ is of positive type? And given that description, is it possible to work out what means when we view $f$ as a finite formal sum of group elements with complex coefficients; i.e., what does that say about the group elements in the sum and what does it say about the complex coefficients?

For reference, see the definition of $\Bbb{k}_r[\Gamma]_+$ on page 4 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.1700.pdf).

Comment: For those of us who don't immediately recognize the term, you should perhaps describe where you encountered it, so we can help you investigate. As it stands we have no idea where to begin (even google searches didn't turn up any viable leads for me.)

Comment: Actually I found one [here](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/baysm/misc/gns/gns.pdf) but it was not clear it was related to group representations.

Comment: @rschwieb I think that is related. Here is specifically where I encountered the term: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.1700.pdf

Comment: @rschwieb See page 4.

Comment: @rschwieb So, putting all this together, it seems that for $f$ to be of positive type means that $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} c_i \overline{c}_j f(g_i^{-1}g_j) \ge 0$ for every collection of group elements $g_1,...,g_n \in G$ and scalars $c_1,...,c_n \in \Bbb{k}$, which is equivalent to saying that $[f(g_i^{-1}g_j)]_{1 \le i,j \le n}$ is a PSD matrix?